# Swift: Instance method as closure not working

Tags: swift, closures

```
var closureA: (String)->()

class Test {
    func instanceMethod(string: String) {
    }
}

let a = Test()

closureA = Test.instanceMethod(a)

closureA("hello")
```

Xcode10 Playground show error:

error: cannot assign value of type '(String) -> ()' to type '(String) -> ()'
closureA = Test.instanceMethod(a)

I already read: https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/

Comment: Isnt it should be `closureA = a.instanceMethod("something")`, `a` is not a String and `Test` is class, not class instance

Comment: @Tj3n nope. a.instanceMethod("something")  means call the method. I want to store the instance method instead of calling it.

Comment: It seems like a bug of playground. Note that you could also have `a.instanceMethod` which has type `(String) -> ()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the point of closure, you can't store the function in the closure, but you can store the piece of code that call to the function with the variable you are passing into the closure, and the function still need a class instance to call it, so it should be like this:

```
var closureA: ((String)->())?

class Test {
    func instanceMethod(string: String) {
        print(string)
    }
}

let a = Test()

//Assume you have a variable `str: String` before hand that will execute the code inside closure
closureA = { str in
    a.instanceMethod(string: str)
}

//Actual call to the closure to execute it
closureA?("hello")
```

Comment: Then the closure is relevant to a.  I would like to store different class same type instance method in this closure.

Comment: And "Global and nested functions, as introduced in Functions, are actually special cases of closures."

Answer (score 0):

I think is the bug of the playground. If we create a temp closure B, and assign it to closure A. Then it works.

```
var closureA: (String)->()

class Test {
    func instanceMethod(string: String) {
        print("Test")
    }
}

let a = Test()

let closureB =  Test.instanceMethod(a)

closureA = closureB

closureA("hello")   // works
```